# Pandas: Randomly sample 5 consecutive rows based on a condition (value in another column)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sampling

For my data, I want to sample 5 lots of 5 consecutive days. For each 'group' of 5-day samples, I want the value in another column to be the same. My data is a time series. Here's a sample:

[image]

Previously, when I was happy with non-consecutive days, I'd use the following code:

```
df.groupby("AGENT").sample(n=5, random_state=1, replace = True)
```

I want it to be random, so I don't just want to take the index for the first new agent and then the subsequent 4 rows.

Comment: please provide your input in a reproducible format

Comment: @mozway Sorry, what do you mean? You mean add more examples of what I've tried?

Comment: No, I meant to not use an image of data: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use a custom [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate):

```
import numpy as np

n = 5
out = (df.groupby('Agent', group_keys=False)
         .apply(lambda g: g.iloc[(x:=np.random.randint(0, len(g)-n)): x+n])
      )
```

If you have python < 3.8:

```
import numpy as np

def random_consecutives(g, n):
    start = np.random.randint(0, len(g)-n)
    return g.iloc[start: start+n]

out = (df.groupby('Agent', group_keys=False)
         .apply(random_consecutives, n=5)
      )
```

Example output:

```
    Agent  Sales (k)        Date
2       1        1.2  21/08/2012
3       1        6.7  22/08/2012
4       1        5.8  23/08/2012
5       1        9.3  24/08/2012
6       1        8.3  25/08/2012
12      2        8.0  06/07/2012
13      2        0.9  07/07/2012
14      2        1.3  08/07/2012
15      2        1.6  09/07/2012
16      2        8.9  10/07/2012
```

Comment: Thank you. Will read the documentation now. I do get an error using this code though. Invalid syntax for this part: x:=

Comment: This is a syntax only supported by python ≥ 3.8 (item assignement operator). Let me rewrite it for older versions.

Comment: Have you tested the updated answer?

Comment: Yeah, didn't work. Doing some further reading now. Will update as soon as I get somewhere. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: How did it "*not work*"? Do you have an error?

Comment: `g` is defined by the `lambda` or is an internal name to the function. You do not need to define it yourself

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly now. Really appreciate it. Will buy you a coffee on the commute to work later. Any other documentation you'd recommend reading to make sure i fully understand this?

Comment: Well, the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs) is a gold mine, although here it's mostly custom code. Don't hesitate to ask if you need clarification